# The plugin lets LAVALAMP the tag "a" is behind, I can not click on the link

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins, z-index

I have the following [site](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/JQvdn/), it use the [LAVALAMP](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/) plugin to make a feature follow the mouse. But I can not click on the link.

What am I doing wrong? Could anyone  give me an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the bottom padding to 0px

```
ul#header-menu li {
    padding: 10px 0 0
}
```

Comment: What is 0? I tried to write 0px but did not work ;
How it works?

Comment: No matter you write 0 or 0px in your css. it's shorthand of padding: top right bottom left. problem solved?

Comment: Yes, solved.
I did not understand the use of padding.
With three parameters?
For me to put 2 are top and button, left and right
putting 4 are top, button, Left, Right
and 3 parameters?

Comment: If you specify the padding with 3 parameter then the 2nd parameter determines the right and left padding and the last one will be the bottom padding.